# Creating a outreach text to leads with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I want to write a small script in which I use data from an excel document and mix it with a text I have that I send to leads.

- Example:

```
Hello (Data-Name), I can see that your business (Data-business) need
some service on (Data-website name). Best regards Jim
```

So if I have 100 leads, then, it must create a document for the data to be inserted into the text and create a new document with the generated text.

I have been trying [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/?ref=lbp) but I was not able to make it work.

Comment: Does it need to be python? Seems like a word [mail merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705) would be what you're looking for.

Comment: I need it to be in py because next level is to make auto message to facebook pages :P